# How to push elements in to an array of an array with a key?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$tab=array(
  "January"=>array(),
  "February"=>array(),
  "March"=>array(),
  "April"=>array(),
  "May"=>array(),
  "June"=>array()
 );

 foreach($tab as $month=>$number){
     for($i=0;$i<6;$i++)
         array_push($number,rand(10,20));
 }
print_r($tab);
?>
```

I'm trying to push multiple numbers into an array which is inside an array where the keys are the names of months. `print_r` displays empty arrays. I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: _“I don't know what I did wrong.”_ - you did not read the manual for `foreach` attentively enough, because it explains what you need to do to manipulate the array you are looping over inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

In his eloquent comment, misorude meant to refer you to this paragraph of the [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) documentation:

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede
>    *$value* with &. In that case the value will be assigned by
>    [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

So, you could change your `foreach` to

```
 foreach ($tab as &$number)
```

(since you don't need the key in your loop, you can omit `$month=>`).